# How to get Object values alone and push into temporary variable - jsPDF-autoTable

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Below is my sample response that I getting from the backend.

```
let data = [
{
    "thisIsTheResponseFromBackEnd": [
    {
        "Col Header 1": "AAA, AAA",
        "Col Header 2": "BCD",
        "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",
    },
    {
        "Col Header 1": "BBB, BBB",
        "Col Header 2": "BCD",
        "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",
    },
    {
        "Col Header 1": "Hello,world",
        "Col Header 2": "BCD",
        "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",

    }]
}]
```

am trying to push dynamic data into jspdf autoTable. i use `header: Object.keys(data[0]) //as column`

but if try to push the value of the object it returns only `[object, Object]`

I tried below possible ways to push data into the body of jspdfatuoTable. but failed the below approach.

```
/*  Object.keys( data ).forEach( key => {
        console.log( data[key] );
        const temp = [data[key]];
        rows.push(temp);
         console.log('body ?', rows);
    }); */

/* Object.keys(data).forEach(function (prop) {
        const temp = [data[prop]];
        rows.push(temp);
    }); */

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {   
    const temp = [data.value];
    rows.push(temp);
    console.log('body ?', rows);
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header: `Object.keys(data[0])[0]`

Body:   `data.map(x => Object.values(x))`

Comment: for header its okay, how could you do that for body since its dynamic. body data may have more different data, `data[0] ` [0] index only consider only one row. what about rest of data?

Answer (score 0):

By For loop u can also solve this easily All u have to do is access ur object properly.

```
    let data = [
    {
        "thisIsTheResponseFromBackEnd": [
        {
            "Col Header 1": "AAA, AAA",
            "Col Header 2": "BCD",
            "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",
        },
        {
            "Col Header 1": "BBB, BBB",
            "Col Header 2": "BCD",
            "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",
        },
        {
            "Col Header 1": "Hello,world",
            "Col Header 2": "BCD",
            "Col Header 3": "dummy data 1",

        }]
    }]


    var res = data[0].thisIsTheResponseFromBackEnd
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      console.log(res[i])
    }
```

Hope it helps